# Simple Javascript function not working

Tags: javascript

I'm wrote a really basic function to display an alert from a button:

```js
function myFunction(name, id) {
  alert(name, id);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction(Doe, AGDJE)">Call</button>
```

Nothing happens. Anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: Your browser console is probably trying to tell you the problem via an error message. The strings in the function call need to be quoted.

Comment: Post browser console error.

Comment: You just need "Doe" and "AGDJE" (between quotes)

Answer (score 2):

`Doe` and `AGDJE` are `strings`, not `variables`.

Quote them like this:

```js
function myFunction(name, id) {
  alert(name +" "+ id);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction('Doe', 'AGDJE')">Call</button>
```

Comment: unless, that is, they are

Comment: Yea, but in his example they are not. Check his fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

2 issues:

1. `alert()` requires 1 argument not 2
2. you must pass the argument using quotes.

Try:

```js
function myFunction(name, id) {
  alert(name +' '+ id);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction('Doe', 'AGDJE')">Call</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try it like this.

String needs to use '' or "" to be interpreted.

```js
function myFunction(name, id) {
  alert(name, id);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction('Doe', 'AGDJE')">Call</button>
```

Comment: Strings can also be initialized by using ticks, like this : `

Comment: Nice, didn't remember that one.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Console (F12 in Chrome). It should give an error like "name Doe is not defined" (same goes for "AGDJE"). That's because you are passing in an identifier and not a string.
 The correct code should be:   `onclick="myFunction('Doe', 'AGDJE')"`

The quotes around `Doe` and `AGDJE` indicate that they are strings and thus needs quotes to be treated as strings.

`alert(name, id)` should also be `alert(name + ' ' + id)`